# Iterate through columns in a dataframe of pyspark without making a different dataframe for a single column

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do we iterate through columns in a dataframe to perform calculations on some or all columns individually in the same dataframe without making a different dataframe for a single column (similar as map iterates through rows in a rdd and performing calculations on a row without making a different rdd for each row).
I reached a solution given below.

```
l = list of column names
df = dataframe in pyspark
def plusone(df_column):
    return (df_column + 1)

df1 = df.select(map(lambda x: (plusone(getattribute(df,l[x]))) if x ==0 else getattribute(df,l[x]), range(len(l))))
print df1.show()
```

In this way, I get a dataframe with changes in a particular column i wanted rather than creating a different dataframe for a column,then merging with the df and removing the old column.

**The problem with this code is it will not be distributed on spark as map iterates over a list. I want something like this in a distributed manner.**

P.S.- I do not want to use an rdd.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using map, use with column on your dataframe with a spark udf.
Inside the udf, define the function and perform your logic, in this way:

1. You are not using list, which are not parallelizable
2. The udf along with the function inside it will be passing to each excutor which will run in parallel.

Comment: Correct me if I understood wrong. Do you mean that I should use map inside a udf and simply call the dataframe inside udf? Because if I simply use udf without map, I will have to pass each column inside udf manually. I want to work on all columns in a single line rather than writing code for each column separately.

Comment: No, pass the entire row(x) like you are already doing uisng lambda x and instead of map define func() to perform your logic inside the udf